# While setting the size of the marker the legend does not show the marker with variable size

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, marker, scatter

the legend in my plot does not show the marker with variable size, but only the one without variable size.
I can not share my dataset. (look the image)
[Hided marker in the legend plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5n4I.png), and the code for it.

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.scatter(c.consumption_kW[c.ch1_state=='rise'],c.chiller1[c.ch1_state=='rise'],
           marker='^',label='Rise',c='blue',s=c['ch1_slope']*4)

ax.scatter(c.consumption_kW[c.ch1_state=='fall'],c.chiller1[c.ch1_state=='fall'],
           marker='v',label='Fall',c='red',s=c['ch1_slope']*4)

ax.scatter(c.consumption_kW[c.ch1_state=='stable'],c.chiller1[c.ch1_state=='stable'],
           marker='o',label='Stable',c='green')

ax.legend()
```

If I do not change the size of the marker the problem does not occur, but the plot il less meaningful.(look the image)
[no sized marker plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LEUZ.png), and the code for it.

```
 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.scatter(c.consumption_kW[c.ch1_state=='rise'],c.chiller1[c.ch1_state=='rise'],
           marker='^',label='Rise',c='blue')

ax.scatter(c.consumption_kW[c.ch1_state=='fall'],c.chiller1[c.ch1_state=='fall'],
           marker='v',label='Fall',c='red')

ax.scatter(c.consumption_kW[c.ch1_state=='stable'],c.chiller1[c.ch1_state=='stable'],
           marker='o',label='Stable',c='green')

ax.legend()
```

Help me.
Thank a lot in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the size for the legend markers by accessing the `legendHandles`. Very simple example based on your code is below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x=range(10)
y=[a*5 for a in x]
z=[a*10 for a in x]

ax.scatter(x, y, marker='^',label='Rise',c='blue',s=x*4)
ax.scatter(y, z, marker='v',label='Fall',c='red',s=y*4)
ax.scatter(x, z, marker='o',label='Stable',c='green')

leg=ax.legend()
# Set the marker size of the first row to 20 and the second row to 30
leg.legendHandles[0].set_sizes([20])
leg.legendHandles[1].set_sizes([30])
plt.show()
```

The result is here.
[image]